# Who are these speedsters in The Legion of Doom (Season 2 Episode 10)?

Tags: dc, character-identification, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

**Warning: mild SPOILER for the tenth episode of the second season of *Legends of Tomorrow* ahead**.

A large part of the episode is devoted to the team trying to find who is the speedster that is against them and Rip Hunter. At some point in the episode, we can see them discussing and pictures (obtained from *The Flash*'s characters) of speedsters appear behind Vixen. The pictures are quite blurry. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

**Who are these speedsters** ?

Here is what I can find. Upper row, for left to right:

1. A speeder with a red domino mask and tight hair. The costume is red with some yellow marks. Then Jessie Quick.
2. Earth-3 Jay Garrick as the Flash.
3. Barry Allen in his Flash costume from Season 2.
4. Very dark picture. Savitar or Zoom?
5. The Rival: black costume, the logo on the chest seems to be a lightning, and the building behind. This is the same as a photo used for advertizing season 2.

Lower row, from left to right:

1. The domino mask and the hair style points to Trajectory.
2. Clearly, Wally West in his Kid Flash costume.

I guess the fourth one on the upper row is Zoom, since the pictures are supposed to be photo from the show, and Savitar cannot seen by anybody except Barry.

Here are the speedsters that appeared in one show without being named above: Eobard Thawne/Reverse Flash (yellow and black costume), Time wraiths and Black Flash (Zoom transformed into a time wraith).

Note that

> because its ancestor Eddy Thawne committed suicide at the end of the first season of *The Flash*, Eobard Thawne has been erased from time and cannot appear on a picture.

Comment: I think 1 was the Reverse Flash.  You say he was "erased from history", and in some ways he was (really the mechanics never made any sense), but... Dr. Stein remembers him.  Everyone in the world remembers the first Harrison Wells as a murderer, even though he was Thawne with a face change.  Why couldn't there be photographs, too?   I think they just discounted him under the "he's dead" theory, until someone brought up the point that he needed help, maybe because he was an abberation.

Comment: I think it is actually Jessie Quick. Because the picture was blurry, I first thought the character was wearing a red hood with some yellow marks. But, after closer inspection, I now believe it is a woman with tigh hair and domino mask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Top Row

- Jesse Quick (Jesse Wells)
- Jay Garrick Earth-3 (likely [this image](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/arrow/images/5/50/Jay_Garrick_greets_Barry.png/revision/latest?cb=20170105221146) based on building in background)
- Barry Allen
- Zoom (Hunter Solomon)
- The Rival (likely [this image](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/arrow/images/a/a3/The_Rival_in_the_Flashpoint_timeline.png/revision/latest?cb=20161005012704) based on building in background)

### Bottom Row

- Trajectory
- Kid Flash (Wally West)

I captured this from Netflix

[image]

And tried to find the closest example of each character to overlay.

[image]